# angular 2 spinner, slider: custom pipe not working

Tags: formatting, pipe, angular2-template

The following is the section of my angular component template that is not working:

```
<p-spinner id="yzDistance"
                           [min]="aRenderState.clipping.planes[0].min"
                           [max]="aRenderState.clipping.planes[0].max"
                           [step]="inputStep"
                           [(ngModel)]="yzDistance" (onChange)="moveClip(0)">
                </p-spinner>

                <input type="range" class="slider" type="range" name="yzDistance"
                       [min]="aRenderState.clipping.planes[0].min"
                       [max]="aRenderState.clipping.planes[0].max"
                       [step]="inputStep"
                       [ngModel]="yzDistance | decimalsPipe"
                       (ngModelChange)="yzDistance=$event"
                       (input)="moveClip(0)">
```

the spinner is working fine showing values formatted correctly e.g 2.009 4.765 -1.649 etc. (3 decimal places). When I move the slider that also has a step of 0.001 the spinner get updated but displays decimals with thousand separators e.g. 3.987,432 -1.34,092 etc. I have tried to correct the problem with the following custom pipe called decimalsPipe:

```
@Pipe({name: 'decimalsPipe'})
export class DecimalsPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value) {

        value.toLocaleString('en-US', {
            minimumFractionDigits: 0,
            maximumFractionDigits: 3
        });
    }
}


@Component({
    selector: 'myComponent',
    templateUrl: './myComponent.html',
    styleUrls: ['./myComponent.css']
})
export class myComponent { ...
```

it still showing the weird decimal formatting and it does not raise errors. Can you help me to sort this out?

Thank you, Dino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u do not return any value in transform , try to return the formatted value in the method transform :

```
transform(value) {

       return value.toLocaleString('en-US', {
            minimumFractionDigits: 0,
            maximumFractionDigits: 3
        });
    }
```

Comment: Still not working but your answer was very useful. I have added a paragraph under the spinner showing {{yzDistance | decimalsPipe}} and I can see that the value is correctly formatted. So the problem is the primeng <p-spinner> that is messing up the format with decimal steps increments.

Answer (score 0):

I have accepted Med_Ali_Rachid answer even if it doesn't work as his answer point me in the right direction. The problem is the spinner that is not formatting the value returned by the pipe.

My solution was to hide the input area of the spinner leaving only the up and down arrows buttons visible. Then I have added a paragraph styled as an input to display the correct value.

```
            <p>
                {{yzDistance | decimalsPipe}}
            </p>

            <p-spinner id="yzDistance"
                       [min]="aRenderState.clipping.planes[0].min"
                       [max]="aRenderState.clipping.planes[0].max"
                       [step]="inputStep"
                       [(ngModel)]="yzDistance" (onChange)="moveClip(0)">
            </p-spinner>
```